# General Solution of a Differential Equation using Green's Function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

My father recently lent me an old textbook of his, called *Mathematical Methods of Physics* by Mathews and Walker. I am working on the following exercise.

> Consider the differential equation
>
> $$y'' + p(x)y' + q(x)y = 0$$
>
> on the interval $x \in [a, b]$. Suppose we know two solutions,
>   $y_1(x)$ and $y_2(x)$, such that
>
> $$\begin{align*} y_1(a) = 0 && y_2(a)\neq0\\ y_1(b) \neq 0 && y_2(b)=0\\ \end{align*}$$
>
> Give the solution of the equation $$y'' + p(x)y' + q(x)y = f(x)$$
>   which satisfies $y(a)=y(b)=0$, in the form $$y(x) = \int_a^b G(x, s)\,f(s) \, ds$$ 
>   where $G(x, s)$, the so-called Green's function,
>   involves only the solutions $y_1$ and $y_2$ and assumes different
>   functional forms for $x<s$ and $s<x$.

Earlier in the chapter, the authors begin to describe the general method for solving these types of equations and leave the completion to the student. This is what I have tried so far, following their advice:

First we seek a solution of the form
$$y=u_1(x)y_1(x) + u_2(x)y_2(x)$$
where the $u_i(x)$ functions are to be determined. We will need the first and second derivatives of this expression in order to solve the differential equation. Thus,
$$y' = u_1y_1' + u_2y_2' + u_1'y_1 + u_2'y_2$$
Before calculating $y''$, the authors suggest to set $u_1'y_1+u_2'y_2=0$ for the sake of convenience. (Anyone have a more sophisticated reasoning for this step?) In any case, I follow suit, and thus we have
$$\begin{align*}
y' &= u_1y_1' + u_2y_2'\\
y'' &= u_1y_1'' + u_2y_2'' + u_1'y_1'+u_2'y_2'
\end{align*}$$

At this point, I plug these representations back into the inhomogeneous equation.
$$[u_1y_1'' + u_2y_2'' + u_1'y_1'+u_2'y_2'] + p(x)[u_1y_1' + u_2y_2'] + q(x)[u_1y_1+u_2y_2] = f(x)$$
Next I reorganize the equation to take advantage of the fact that $y_1$ and $y_2$ solve the homogeneous equation.
$$u_1[y_1''+p(x)y_1'+q(x)y_1] + u_2[y_2''+p(x)y_2'+q(x)y_2] + u_1'y_1'+u_2'y_2'= f(x)$$
The first two terms in the sum equal zero by assumption, thus
$$u_1'y_1'+u_2'y_2'= f(x)$$
We also have the following equation, by our "convenient assumption"
$$u_1'y_1+u_2'y_2=0$$

Hence, $u_1'=\dfrac{-u_2'y_2}{y_1}$, which we then substitute to find $u_2'$
$$\begin{align*}
\dfrac{-u_2'y_2}{y_1}y_1'+u_2'y_2'&= f(x)\\
u_2'&= \dfrac{y_1f(x)}{y_2'y_1-y_2y_1'}\\
\end{align*}$$
which gives us $u_2'$ purely in terms of the $y_i$'s and $f$, allowing us to find a similar expression for $u_1'$
$$ u_1'=-\dfrac{y_2f(x)}{y_2'y_1-y_2y_1'} $$

[EDIT: This is where I was originally stuck. The rest of the solution is as follows, courtesy comment below from @icurays1]

Finally we have our expression for $y$,
$$\begin{align*}
y&=-y_1\int_a^b\dfrac{y_2f(s)}{y_2'(s)y_1(s)-y_2(s)y_1'(s)}ds + y_2\int_a^b\dfrac{y_1f(s)}{y_2'(s)y_1(s)-y_2(s)y_1'(s)} ds\\
y(x)&=-\int_a^b\dfrac{y_1(x)y_2(s)f(s)}{y_2'y_1-y_2y_1'}ds + \int_a^b\dfrac{y_2(x)y_1(s)f(s)}{y_2'(s)y_1(s)-y_2(s)y_1'(s)} ds\\
\end{align*}$$
and we reach the desired form:
$$y(x)=\int_a^b\dfrac{y_2(x)y_1(s)-y_1(x)y_2(s)}{y_2'y_1-y_2y_1'}f(s)ds$$

Comment: Alternate hints: the Green's function must be continuous, and the derivative will have a jump along $x=s$.

Comment: So I went ahead with solving for the $u_i'$'s but I can't seem to figure out how to work $s$ into the equation... Any advice?

Comment: @Orangutango I have a much simpler method of finding Green's functions, but it would be different than the method your book seems to describe.

Comment: Reference? I am interested. Although, I would like to still settle this problem in the manner presented.

Comment: @Orangutango I'll post a brief description of the method as an answer.

Comment: @Amzoti I noticed you answered a more specific question involving variation of parameters. Do you know how I could turn my last line of derivation into the desired form?

Comment: @Orangutango Actually, I think your solution is complete - the $s$ comes as the integration variable in those two integrals.  My method is only really faster if your operator is in Sturm-Liouville form ($py^{\prime\prime}+p^\prime y^\prime+qy$).

Comment: @Orangutango: See https://math.uc.edu/~halpern/diffeqns/Handouts/Variationofparametergreensfn.pdf

Comment: OH! My issue was using $dx$ as the infinitesimal, when it really should be $ds$.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Well, the problem of finding the solution to
$$
y'' + p(x) y' + q(x) y = f(x)
$$
when the solutions $y_1$ and $y_2$ of the homogeneous problem are "known" is in some thinking, the following:

I know $y(x) = c_1 y_1(x) + c_2 y_2(x)$ solves
$$
y'' + p(x) y' + q(x) y = 0.
$$
What if I let $c_1$ and $c_2$ vary, in order to satisfy point by point, the non-homogeneous equation. I propose then $y(x) = c_1(x) y_1(x) + c_2(x) y_2(x)$, and see where it leads me. For that, we calculate
$$
y'(x) = c_1(x) y_1'(x) + c_2(x) y_2'(x) + c_1'(x) y_1(x) + c_2'(x) y_2(x),
$$
and $y''$. Before doing that, let's take a look on $y'(x)$. If we let the terms of the first derivative of $c_1$, and $c_2$ to subsist, then $y''$ will have terms of the second derivative on $c_1$ and $c_2$, and we will achieve nothing in terms of simplicity. What was a second order ODE with one unknown ($y$), will become a second order ODE with two unknowns ($c_1$ and $c_2$), with the lack of a second equation. This is why, in the construction, one asks for 
$$
c_1'(x) y_1(x) + c_2'(x) y_2(x) = 0.
$$
If this condition is fulfilled, we achieve one very important thing: to reduce the non-homogeneous second order ODE, to a system of two first order ODEs, which, incidentally, we know how to solve *exaclty* (modulus integration). This would be one *rational* explanation in choosing the above condition.

Now back to the problem at hand. When one has initial conditions, the problem is stated in the following way:
$$
y'' + p(x) y' + q(x) y = f(x), \quad y(a) = y_0, \quad y'(a) = y_0', \quad a < x < b.
$$

The easiest way to solve the full problem is to take advantage of the linearity and split it in two:
$$
y_h'' + p(x) y_h' + q(x) y = 0, \quad y_h(a) = y_0, \quad y_h'(a) = y_0',
$$

and

$$
y_p'' + p(x) y_p' + q(x) y = f(x), \quad y_p(a) = 0, \quad y_p'(a) = 0,
$$

and then $y(x) = y_h(x) + y_p(x)$. In other words, we solve the homogeneous ODE with non-homogeneous initial conditions, and then the non-homogeneous ODE with homogeneous initial conditions, treating the non-homogeneities separately.

The homogeneous solution will be
$$
y_h(x) = k_1 y_1(x) + k_2 y_2(x),
$$
where $y_1$ and $y_2$ are the two linearly independent solutions, and $k_1$ and $k_2$ are determined by solving the system
$$
\begin{pmatrix} y_1(a) & y_2(a) \\ y_1'(a) & y_2'(a) \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} k_1 \\ k_2 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} y_0 \\ y_0' \end{pmatrix}.
$$

For $y_p$, we propose the solution
$$
y_p(x) = c_1(x) y_1(x) + c_2(x) y_2(x)
$$
with the condition $c_1'(x) y_1(x) + c_2(x) y_2(x) = 0$ (explained above). Then, substituting in its ODE, we can determine $c_1(x)$ and $c_2(x)$ by solving the system
$$
\begin{pmatrix} y_1(x) & y_2(x) \\ y_1'(x) & y_2'(x) \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} c_1'(x) \\ c_2'(x) \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ f(x) \end{pmatrix}
$$
and then
\begin{align}
c_1'(x) &= -\frac{y_2(x) f(x)}{W(y_1,y_1)(x)} \\
\\
c_2'(x) &= \frac{y_1(x) f(x)}{W(y_1,y_2)(x)}
\end{align}
where $W(y_1,y_2)(x) = y_1 y_2'- y_1' y_2$ is the Wronskian of $y_1$ and $y_2$.

**The key** here is that, in order to obtain $c_1$ and $c_2$, **one has to integrate**. To do this, we need limits of integration. Conveniently, we know the initial conditions for $y_p$; they can be read as
$$
\begin{pmatrix} y_1(a) & y_2(a) \\ y_1'(a) & y_2'(a) \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} c_1(a) \\ c_2(a) \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}
$$
This means that $c_1(a) = c_2(a) = 0$. Finally, performing the integration,
$$
\int_{a}^x c_1'(s) ds = c_1(x) = -\int_{a}^x \frac{y_2(s)}{W(s)} f(s) ds
$$
$$
\int_{a}^x c_2'(s) ds = c_2(x) = \int_{a}^x \frac{y_1(s)}{W(s)} f(s) ds
$$
and then
$$
y_p(x) = \int_{a}^x \frac{y_1(s) y _2(x) - y_1(x)y_2(s)}{W(s)} f(s) ds
$$
or
$$
y_p(x) = \int_{a}^{b} g(x,s) f(s) ds
$$
where
$$
g(x,s) = \begin{cases} \frac{y_1(s) y _2(x) - y_1(x)y_2(s)}{W(s)} & \mbox{if }a < s < x \\
0 & \mbox{if } x < s < b \end{cases}
$$
Finally
$$
y(x) = k_1(x) y_1(x) + k_2(x) y_2(x) + \int_a^b g(x,s) f(s) ds.
$$
The function $g(x,s)$ is called [Green's function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_function), and is completely associated with the problem 
$$
L y = \frac{d^2 y}{d x^2} + p(x) \frac{d y}{d x} + q(x) y = f(x), \quad B y = \begin{pmatrix} y(a) \\ y'(a) \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}, \quad a < x < b
$$

The Green's functions is some sort of "inverse" of the *operator* $L$ with boundary conditions $B$.

**What happens with boundary conditions on $a$ and $b$?**

Well, in this case, the boundary conditions $B$ are of the form
$$
By = \begin{pmatrix} \alpha_1 y(a) + \beta_1 y'(a) + \gamma_1 y(b) + \delta_1 y'(b) \\ \alpha_2 y(a) + \beta_2 y'(a) + \gamma_2 y(b) + \delta_2 y'(b) \end{pmatrix}
$$
and need not to be homogeneous, i.e. $B y = (r_1, r_2)^T$. If the boundary conditions are linearly independent, then the problem is well defined, and we have to solve
$$
L y = f(x), \quad B y = (r_1, r_2)^T, \quad a < x < b.
$$
The case where $\alpha_2 = \beta_1 = \gamma_{1,2} = \delta_{1,2} = 0$ is the well known initial condition problem, solved above. The case $\gamma_1 = \delta_1 = \alpha_2 = \beta_2 = 0$ is called unmixed, while the other is mixed. Examples of unmixed boundary conditions are Dirichlet conditions $y(a) = y(b) = 0$, Neumann conditions $y'(a) = y'(b)$ and Robin conditions $y(a) + \alpha y'(a) = y(b) + \beta y'(b) = 0$. Examples of mixed boundary conditions are periodic $y(a) = y(b)$, $y'(a) = y'(b)$, and antiperiodic $y(a) = -y(b)$, $y'(a) = -y'(b)$.

As with initial conditions, the best way to work is to split the problem in two:
$$
L y_h = 0, \quad B y_h = (r_1, r_2)^T
$$
and
$$
L y_p = f(x), \quad B y_p = (0, 0)^T
$$
Solving for $y_h$ is equivalent for all types of boundary conditions, and I'll ignore this problem (if you have doubts is a good exercise to work out the details yourself).

**Unmixed boundary conditions**

$$
B y = \begin{pmatrix} B_1 y \\ B_2 y \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} \alpha_1 y(a) + \beta_1 y'(a) \\ \gamma_2 y(b) + \delta_2 y'(b) \end{pmatrix} = 0
$$

Let $w_1(x) = h_{11} y_1(x) + h_{22} y_2(x)$, and $w_2(x) = h_{12} y_1(x) + h_{22} y_2(x)$ with $h_{ij}$ constants, such that $B_1 w_1 = 0$ and $B_2 w_2 = 0$. We propose
$$
y_p(x) = c_1(x) w_1(x) + c_2(x) w_2(x)
$$
with the (very natural) condition $c_1'(x) w_1(x) + c_2'(x) w_2(x) = 0$. As in the initial conditions problem, it's easy to see that
\begin{align}
c_1'(x) &= -\frac{w_2(x) f(x)}{W(w_1,w_2)(x)}\\
\\
c_2'(x) &= \frac{w_1(x) f(x)}{W(w_1,w_2)(x)}
\end{align}
where $W(w_1,w_2)(x) = W(x)$ is the Wronskian of $w_1$ and $w_2$. To determine the limits of integration, we simply evaluate the boundary condtions:
\begin{align} 
B_1 y_p &= c_1(a) B_1 w_1 + c_2(a) B_1 w_2 = c_2(a) B_1 w_2 = 0\\
B_2 y_p &= c_1(b) B_2 w_1 + c_2(b) B_2 w_2 = c_1(b) B_2 w_1 = 0
\end{align}
This relation tells us that $c_1$ and $c_2$ need to fulfill the conditions $c_2(a) = c_1(b) = 0$, in order to satisfy the boundary conditions. Then
$$
\int_x^b c_1'(s) ds = - c_1(x) = \int_x^b \frac{w_2(s)}{W(s)}f(s) ds
$$
and
$$
\int_a^x c_2(s) ds = c_2(x) = \int_a^x \frac{w_1(s)}{W(s)}f(s) ds
$$
Finally
$$
y_p(x) = \int_x^b \frac{w_1(x)w_2(s)}{W(s)} f(s) ds + \int_a^x \frac{w_2(x) w_1(s)}{W(s)} f(s) ds
$$
or
$$
y_p(s) = \int_a^b g(x,s) f(s) ds
$$
where
$$
g(x,s) = \begin{cases} \frac{w_1(s) w_2(x)}{W(s)} & \mbox{if } a < s < x < b\\
\\
\frac{w_1(x) w_2(s)}{W(s)} & \mbox{if } a < x < s < b\end{cases}
$$

**Mixed boundary conditions**

The easiest way here would be to use the result above. Let
$$
y_1(x) = c_{11}(x) w_{11}(x) + c_{12}(x) w_{12}(x)
$$
and
$$
y_2(x) = c_{21}(x) w_{21}(x) + c_{22}(x) w_{22}(x)
$$
where $w_{11}$, $w_{12}$, $w_{21}$, $w_{22}$, are chosen in order to fulfill
$$
B_1 y_1 = \begin{pmatrix} \alpha_1 y_1(a) + \beta_1 y_1'(a) \\ \gamma_2 y_1(b) + \delta_2 y_1'(b)\end{pmatrix} = 0
$$
and
$$
B_2 y_2 = \begin{pmatrix} \gamma_1 y_2(b) + \delta_1 y_2'(b) \\ \alpha_2 y_2(a) + \beta_2 y_2'(a)\end{pmatrix} = 0
$$

By construction, let
\begin{align}
y_1(x) &= \frac{1}{2}\int_a^b g_1(x,s) f(s) ds\\
\\
y_2(x) &= \frac{1}{2}\int_a^b g_2(x,s) f(s) ds
\end{align}
where
\begin{align}
g_1(x,s) &= \begin{cases} \frac{w_{11}(s) w_{12}(x)}{W(s)} & \mbox{if } a < s < x < b\\
\\
\frac{w_{11}(x) w_{12}(s)}{W(s)} & \mbox{if } a < x < s < b\end{cases}
\\ \\
g_2(x,s) &= \begin{cases} \frac{w_{21}(s) w_{22}(x)}{W(s)} & \mbox{if } a < s < x < b\\
\\
\frac{w_{21}(x) w_{22}(s)}{W(s)} & \mbox{if } a < x < s < b\end{cases}
\end{align}
Then, taking $y(x) = y_h(x) + y_1(x) + y_2(x)$, where $y_h(x) = k_1 y_1(x) + k_2 y_2(x)$, we have
$$
L y = L y_h + L y_1 + L y_2 = L y_1 + L y_2 = \frac{1}{2}f(x) + \frac{1}{2}f(x) = f(x)
$$
and
\begin{align}
B y &= B y_h + B y_1 + B y_2 \\
&= B y_h + B_1 y_1 + B_1 y_2 + B_2 y_1 + B_2 y_2 \\
&= B y_h + B_2 y_1 + B_1 y_2 = \begin{pmatrix} r_1 \\ r_2 \end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
If we choose $k_1$ and $k_2$ in such way that
$$
B y_h = \begin{pmatrix} r_1 \\ r_2 \end{pmatrix} - B_2 y_1 - B_1 y_2
$$
then
$$
y(x) = y_h(x) + y_1(x) + y_2(x) = y_h(x) + \int_a^b g(x,s) f(s) ds
$$
where
$$
g(x,s) = \begin{cases} \frac{w_{11}(s) w_{12}(x) + w_{21}(s) w_{22}(x)}{2 W(s)} & \mbox{if } a < s < x < b\\
\\
\frac{w_{11}(x) w_{12}(s) + w_{21}(x) w_{22}(s)}{2W(s)} & \mbox{if } a < x < s < b\end{cases}
$$

A very thorough treatment of the construction of Green's functions for second order ODEs can be found in the fantastic book *Principles and Techniques of Applied Mathematics*, by Bernard Friedman.

Comment: A really great answer! This explanation deserves more attention.

Comment: Is it a typo that k1 and k2 become function of x just before the definition of the Green function?

Comment: @chris It's a typo.